# c# smartphone-like scrolling windows forms panel movement

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I will try to explain it: I'm making an touch app in windows forms. I have some panels with buttons inside. I would like to move ( right or left ) the panel when i click in any control inside the panel and move the mouse left or right. I would like to get the movement like smartphone scrolling.

I thought to make this with drag&drop and when I drag some control inside the panel, move the panel to right or left. But I don't know how to make this and I don't want to lose button's click because every button have their own functionality.

You have some idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: A while ago I found an example of what you're trying to do, although it's in WPF: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PhoneLikeControl.aspx Myabe it'll help. About not losing OnClick event, I don't know if it's possible, but maybe call base.OnClick when overriding OnMouseUp or something?

Comment: Thanks a lot! it's just I was looking for. but it's very sophisticated and it has so much code because it's impressive, I don't need so much, but anyway I would try it asap!